# About function pointers in C

Tags: c, parameters, function-declaration

what is the magic on the `finding` function below?

1) what is this inner mechanism that allows `match` to be used without being declared previously?

2) In `main` , shouldn't the `finding` call pass the array `ADS` along with `sports_no_trucks`?

Thanks in advance!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int NUM_ADS = 2;
char *ADS[] = {
    "Luis: SLM ND likes sports, theater, art",
    "Mike: DWM DS likes trucks, sports"
};

void finding(int (*match) (char *))
{
    int i;
    puts("Search results:");
    puts("------------------------------------");
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ADS; i++)
    {
        if (match(ADS[i]))
        {
            printf("%s\n", ADS[i]);
        }
    }
    puts("------------------------------------");
}

int sports_no_trucks(char *s)
{
    return strstr(s, "sports") && !strstr(s, "trucks");
}


int main()
{

    finding(sports_no_trucks);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Close "dupe" of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work). `match` is a pointer to a function. It's declared in the parameter list.

Comment: match is a function parameter parameter. The function prototype declares it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this function declaration

```
void finding(int (*match) (char *));
```

there is declared one parameter with the name `match` that has the type of pointer to function of the type `int( char * )`. That is the parameter `match` itself has the type `int ( * )( char * )`.

In the call of the function `finding`

```
finding(sports_no_trucks);
```

there is passed as an argument function designator `sports_no_trucks` that corresponds to the following definition of the function

```
int sports_no_trucks(char *s)
{
    return strstr(s, "sports") && !strstr(s, "trucks");
}
```

So the parameter `match` of the function `finding` gets the value of the pointer to the function `sports_no_trucks`  because function designators used in expressions are converted to pointers to functions.

You can imagine the definition of the function `finding` and its call the following way

```
finding(sports_no_trucks);

//...

void finding( /* int (*match) (char *) */ )
{
    int ( *match )( char * ) = sports_no_trucks;
    //...
}
```

To make it more clear you can introduce a typedef name like

```
typedef int FN( char * );
```

In this case the declaration of the function finding will look like

```
void finding( FN *match );
```

where `FN` is an alias for the function type `int( char * )`.

> 2) In main , shouldn't the finding call pass the array ADS along with
>   sports_no_trucks?

The array declared as a global variable

```
int NUM_ADS = 2;
char *ADS[] = {
    "Luis: SLM ND likes sports, theater, art",
    "Mike: DWM DS likes trucks, sports"
};
```

And the function `finding` has access to it because it is visible in the file scope of the program

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_ADS; i++)
{
    if (match(ADS[i]))
    {
        printf("%s\n", ADS[i]);
    }
}
```

But you are right. It is a bad style of programming when functions depend on global variables. In this case you are unable to call the function for another array. So this function is not a general function. It is very specific and can deal with only one array.

There was no need to declare the array as global and define the function that depends on the global array.

In this case the function declaration can look like

```
void finding( char * s[], size_t n, int (*match) (char *));
```

and the function could be called for the array ADS like

```
finding( ADS, NUM_ADS, sports_no_trucks );
```

But it could be called for any other array the same way

```
finding( AnotherArray, ItsSize, sports_no_trucks );
```

Answer (score 0):

`int name(char *s)` declares `name` to be a function taking a `char *s` argument and returning an `int`.

`int (*name)(char *s)` declares `name` to be a pointer to a function of that type.

In `void finding(int (*match) (char *))`, we see the parameter `match` declared as described above.

> 1) what is this inner mechanism that allows `match` to be used without being declared previously?

`match` is declared before it is used; in `void finding(int (*match) (char *))`, it is declared to be a parameter to the function `finding`, with the type described above.

> 2) In `main` , shouldn't the `finding` call pass the array `ADS` along with `sports_no_trucks`?

It does not have to because `ADS` is declared outside any function and before `finding` is defined, so `ADS` is visible to the code inside `finding`. (Using external identifiers like this is generally considered bad design if it can be avoided.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be easier to understand in this form

```
typedef int functype(char *);

void finding(functype *func)
{
    /* ... */    
}
```

`functype` is type of function returning `int` and taking parameter of `char *`

`functype *func` is a pointer to this type. And now it looks as any other pointer

ADS is a global variable which can accessed everywhere in the program.